# Music/podcast player with speed control?

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3-player

I am looking for a MP3/Ogg player that has the ability to playback a file at a higher speed, preferably without affecting the pitch. What players allow that? The only one I know right now is `alsaplayer`, but it can't do it without affecting the pitch and also has currently a bug that causes it to use 100% of the CPU at all times, so that renders it kind of unusable. What alternatives are out there?

Comment: There's a bug filed on `alsaplayer` about the 100% CPU usage, right? If not, will you please file a bug about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [playitslowly](http://packages.ubuntu.com/playitslowly)

Different to the suggestion of the application's name this player is able to change to a higher or lower pitch or to different playback speeds. Also included is the ability to loop over a section of the audio file (for transcription purposes), and to save the file at a given different speed.

[image]

<sup>Screenshot from [Debian](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/playitslowly)</sup>

The package is in the repositories (universe) from Ubuntu >=11.04. Here is the [project's home page](http://29a.ch/playitslowly/). The player is based on gstreamer, so any files compatible with that will be played.

Comment: VLC is capable of keeping the pitch as well when activating the "scale audio tempo in sync with playback rate" filter which can be found under advanced options.