# looking for a music player to control speed and transpose songs

Tags: sound, music

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am looking for a **music player** that is able to **control the speed of a song and transpose** **it easily**. 
I know VLC media player can change the speed but its a bit complicated and its getting annoying after a short time of using it.
The player should be able to play .mp3 data, MIDI ability would be  nice but is not necessary.

Comment: Have a look at playitslowly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87707/music-podcast-player-with-speed-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know, your question is somewhat prone to opinions. My suggestion is Audacity.

See http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

It is a cross platform application (although frustrating there is not a port for android >_< )

You can change the tempo without changing the pitch. I use it for music lessons as students can play along but adjust the speed of playback.

If audacity does not have the features you want, update your question with specific features you lack.